# Navigating Student Health Accommodations: A Delicate Balance

Tags: teaching

I occasionally encounter situations where students present medical notes from their doctors, citing conditions like headaches or general anxiety. These diagnoses often rely on the students' self-reported symptoms. While I'm inclined to question the authenticity of such claims, I'm also aware that the students might genuinely be struggling with physical or mental health issues. Given that our institution typically reserves accommodations for more severe cases (e.g., hospitalization), I'm seeking advice on how to approach these situations. Specifically, is it appropriate to offer minor adjustments or support, such as deadline extensions or quiz retake opportunities, to these students?

Comment: Does your institution have policy and offices to deal with these things?

Comment: Only that if student has severe illness.

Comment: At institutions I'm familiar with, this isn't really up to individual instructors: the specific accomodations for a student are specified by the office that handles these things, and that's the office to direct these notes to. Other things you do as an instructor to accommodate students should be for everyone, e.g. consider the (in)flexibility of your deadlines and retake opportunities while keeping in mind the various struggles any student may be facing at a given time. Does your institution do this?

Comment: Not really. The specific office in change of accommodation in general only grant special accommodations when it's severe case, such as these need hospitalization. Of course if I offer the opportunity to one student who comes with a medical note, I do the same things for everyone. I also only give minor helps in these cases.

Comment: If the uni does not have a good support system, you set up your own set of rules of policy and try to consistently employ it. You definitely want to decouple your policy-level decision-making from the concrete case as much as possible.

Comment: What is your country/jurisdiction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a standard rule that the one lowest (possibly null) test and assignment will be dropped for each student. If a student has a "minor" problem, they can use this drop-item to cover it -- whether it's being sick for a day, or late from traffic, or whatever.

I don't read or assess doctor's notes. This policy triggers no added follow-up work on my part. Dropping an item is built into the digital LMS so it's convenient. Students always embrace this when I point it out in these situations.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, if the students have a note from a medical professional, it is not my place to wonder about the "authenticity" of the condition (whether I believe it's based on self-reporting or not - I would assume that medical professionals have ethical standards that would prevent them from writing notes they thought were unreasonable. Further, cases like severe anxiety, which can be crippling, often can't be witnessed by the doctor but are genuine - I don't see how I can be judge of the authenticity or not).

I would lean on the side of accommodating the students and have been doing so. I have several students with anxiety and migraines that have been reported through the university's accommodations office; with each of them, I agree on what accommodations would be most reasonable for them - some of them, unfortunately, have to miss class regularly because of their condition and I say that's fine but we have an agreement that (1) they let me know at least 10 mins before class that they won't make it and (2) they make sure to catch up. This system has worked quite well for my students.

Comment: So the students still need to go through the university's accommodation office in order to make such agreement with you, is that correct?

Comment: @NonalcoholicBeer that is the default way to go for chronic conditions. It is in the students own interest to pursue this official channel